# How to find any control present within the clicked row in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I am trying to create nested comments.
The below code is giving me Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

```
protected void GridViewRowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var scrapId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    { 
        case "comment":
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow gvRow = GridViewUserScraps.Rows[index];
            TextBox txtcomment = (TextBox)GridViewUserScraps.Rows[index].FindControl("txtcomment");

            string postcomment = "Insert INTO comment (FromId,ToId,PostId,CommentMsg) VALUES('" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + "','" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "','" + scrapId + "','"+txtcomment.Text+"')";
            dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(postcomment);

            break;
    }
}
```

The datakeyname is .. `DataKeyNames="ScrapId"`

I wan to pass the values of textbox which lies in the same row as the button which i click to post.

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Comment" CommandName="comment" 
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>' />
```

Comment: What is the tag that is firing the event? It is weird you are using the `e.CommandArgument` for both `scrapId` and `index`

Comment: see my edit, i have mentioned the code of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the row index like:

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int index = gvr.RowIndex;
```

Generally the `commandArgument` contains the rowIndex by default, but in your case, you are overwriting it in your tag, with the `Eval("ScrapId")`.

The `e` is an object containing information about the event that was fired. `ComandSource` is the source control that fired the event, in your case, the Button, so we cast is to Button.
Than, we have the `NamingContainer`, that is the server control that wraps your Button, in this case a `GridViewRow`.

With the `GridViewRow`, we have access directly to the active row at the time of the event, and there we have more data about the row, including the current `RowIndex`

Comment: RIght on spot!!! YOur code worked. Can you please explain your code in a little detail. What is NamingContainer for?